# Why does FFT of sine wave have magnitudes in multiple bins

Tags: fft, web-audio-api

I've been playing around with Web Audio some. I have a simple oscillator node playing at a frequency of context.sampleRate / analyzerNode.fftSize * 5 (107.666015625 in this case). When I call analyzer.getByteFrequencyData I would expect it to have a value in the 5th bin, and no where else. What I actually see is `[0,0,0,240,255,255,255,240,0,0...]`

Why am I getting values in multiple bins?

Comment: How long is your FFT window size? And the time series vector you pass for calculation?

Comment: context.sampleRate = 44100
analyzer.fftSize = 2048

Comment: So how much spectral leakage do you have with a frequency of 118.4326171875Hz?

Answer (score 1):

The webaudio AnalyserNode applies a Blackman window before computing the FFT.  This windowing function will smear the single tone.

Comment: The FFT will smear into surrounding bins ... the rectangular window  (ie no windowing) would be much much worse.

Answer (score 0):

That has to do that your sequence is finite and therefore your signal is supposed to last for a finite amount of time. Surely you are calculating the FFT with a rectangular window, i.e. your signal is consider to last for the amount of generated samples only and that "discontinuity" (i.e. the fact that the signal has a finite number of samples) creates the [spectral leakage](http://www.ece.uci.edu/docs/hspice/hspice_2001_2-220.html). To minimise this effect, you could try several windows functions that when applied to your data prior the FFT calculation, reduces this effect.

Comment: There is no discontinuity when an unmodulated signal is a exactly periodic in the FFT aperture, which 107.66 Hz is, in a window of 2048 at a 44.1k sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be clipping somewhere in your computation by using a test signal too large for your data or arithmetic format.  Try again using a floating point format.

Comment: In case it's not clear, I'm not actually doing any computation myself, but am calling getByteFrequencyData on an AnalyserNode. If I instead call getFloatFrequencyData, the results seem to follow a similar pattern `-183.1167755126953,-178.00262451171875,-190.38323974609375,-33.979400634765625,-18.06180191040039,-13.55561637878418,-18.06180191040039,-33.979400634765625,-195.78549194335938...`